# Database query failedYou have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

here is the Error
Database query failedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' )' at line 4..

im so tired to fixed this error and i dont know what should i do..

```
<form id="packageLessonType" method="post">
<table id="listpackage" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
<thead>
<tbody id="responsePackage">
<tr id="pack_1">
<td>1 Month Unlimited</td>
<td id="td-" class="center">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="package[]">
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="pack_2">
<td>6 Lessons</td>
<td id="td-" class="center">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="package[]">
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="pack_3">
<td>6 Months Unlimited</td>
<td id="td-" class="center">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="package[]">
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="pack_4">
<td>12 Months Unlimited</td>
<td id="td-" class="center">
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="package[]">
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="pack_5">
<td>Group of 4</td>
<td id="td-" class="center">
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="package[]">
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="pack_6">
<td>Group of 8 </td>
<td id="td-" class="center">
<input type="checkbox" value="6" name="package[]">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Ajax Script

```
$('.packAddLt_btn').click(function(e){
        var clickedIdadded = this.id.split('_');
        var addedId = clickedIdadded[1];
        var addedPackageLesson = "&lessonPackageAdded="+addedId;
        var addLesPackCheck = $('#packageLessonType').serialize();
        var submitData = addLesPackCheck+addedPackageLesson;
        //alert(submitData);

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/includes/response_lessons_packages.php",
            dataType:"text",
            data:submitData,
            success: function(response){

                alert(response);
                },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOtions, thrownError){
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });

        });
```

PHP CODE

```
if($_POST['package']){

            $checkBox= $_POST['package'];
            $idToBeAdded = $_POST['lessonPackageAdded'];

            foreach($checkBox as $value){
                $queryAdd = "INSERT INTO packagebylessontype (packageid)VALUE({$value}) WHERE lessontypeid = {$idToBeAdded}";
                $addedLessonByPackage = mysql_query($queryAdd, $connection);
                }
                confirm_query($addedLessonByPackage);

            if($addedLessonByPackage){
                echo "You've successfuly deleted your Package..";
                mysql_close($connection);
                }else{
                header('HTTP/1.1 500 Looks like mysql error, could not insert record!');
                exit();

                }   

    }
```

Error:

Database query failedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' )' at line 4

Comment: side note: `id` cannot be duplicated.

Comment: its `values`, and having a `where` clause on insertion doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error - instead of VALUE type VALUES.

Also you are not properly escaping your sql params thus leading yourself open to sql injections.

Comment: Ah sorry :) I was posting from my mobile so i could not see the rest of the query with WHERE. That's true - you can't use conditions with INSERT. What you want is to also insert the lessontypeid (incase you really want to insert) OR use an UPDATE query - like "manuelbcd" said above.

Comment: In case you wanted to do an insert - here it is: INSERT INTO packagebylessontype (packageid, lessontypeid) VALUES ({$value}, {$idToByAdded});

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use INSERT statement with WHERE clause in a simple query. An INSERT will create a new row with his own field lessontypeid.  Maybe you are trying to perform an update.

If you want to make an insert, the correct way would be:

```
INSERT INTO packagebylessontype (packageid) VALUES ('A')
```

If you want to perform an update, then:

```
UPDATE packagebylessontype SET packageid = 'A' WHERE lessontypeid ='1'
```

Please note that I'm using WHERE clause only in UPDATE operation, as a reference to locate register to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Well give a space between (packageid) and VALUES, I think this might work and ofcourse it should be VALUES not VALUE

Answer (score 0):

try with VALUES instead of VALUE
$queryAdd = "INSERT INTO packagebylessontype (packageid)**VALUES**({$value}) WHERE lessontypeid = {$idToBeAdded}";